# .Net Multilanguage Website

Tags: .net, multilingual

I have a .net website in Italian and English. The Italian is in the root, while the English is in a folder (/en). I would like to automatically redirect my non Italian users to the English version of my website.

how can I do that? Moreover, is it possible to give the chance to override the redirect (i.e. if someone is Italian but has an English browser, can he go back to the Italian version of the website?)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

for me the best way is to show in all pages a button to give the possibility to everyone to swith from a language to another.
To check the preferred language set in the browser of the user u can use this:
HttpRequest.UserLanguages
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx

next time u can use the 'localization' ability of the .net ;)

Comment: I am providing the language button to users but I would like to provide the URL to non Italian users and I don't want them to land on an Italian website...